# change django default date template format

Tags: html, django, django-templates, frontend

I'm a newbie and I have a date format 2017-12-30, but when the date is passed on template it returns Dec. 30, 2017. I tried to do this but it is not working

```
<div class="first-row">
            <div class="document-item-title"|date:'Y-m-d'>
              {{list.document_date.display_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="document-item-detail">
                <input type="text" id="date" class="select-date"
                       name="{{list.document_date.name}}" value="{{list.document_date.select}}">
            </div>
          </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using date templatetag at incorrect place. Assuming this document_date has the date that needs to be printed change this  `{{list.document_date.display_name}}`

to

`{{list.document_date | date:'Y-m-d'}}`

I guess display_name is the method which converts the date in this format. which we do not require here.

Also, change

```
<div class="document-item-title"|date:'Y-m-d'>
```

to

```
<div class="document-item-title">
```